# Fade div on hover and display additional text on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to fade out a div when you hover over it and then display text on top of that div. I can accomplish the fade out a number of ways; however, I'm struggling to find a way to combine the fade out with displaying the additional text. Here's what I have as far as the fade out:

HTML

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="myDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.myDiv{
    width: 200px;    
}

.myDiv:hover{
    opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6go1hdy/)

I want the whole `div` to be a hyperlink to another page, and when the user hovers over the `div`, the main text fades out and text such as "Click here to view more" displays on top of the faded text.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: you cannot have `div` tags inside `a` tags. you need to fix that first. Maybe make them `span` instead

Comment: So you want to do without using any library ??
And also should work on all the browsers.

Comment: Im assuming you need to do this without using Javascript right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the first problem I see here is that you need to replace the `div` with `span` tags for semantic HTML. Next your `transitions` should be set on the element without the hover selector, so that when you hover in and out, the transition still applies. Check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k491yha9/4/)** I created to help you understand it.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="mainSpan">Lorem ipsum dolodfsd fs fdsd sd fsd fsdf sdf sdf sd fsdf r sit amet</span>
    <span class="hoverSpan">Click Here</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;    
    display:block;
}
a>span{
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover .mainSpan{
    opacity: .3;
}

.hoverSpan{
    opacity:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}

a:hover .hoverSpan{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set span with `absolute` positioning after your div and set 0  for its opacity , like this :

```
<a href="#"><div class="myDiv">TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<span style='position:absolute;z-index:999;top:50px;'>Click here For more Details</span>
```

and make it visible on hover :

```
.myDiv
    {
    width: 200px;    
    }
span{
    opacity:0;
}
.myDiv:hover 
    {
    opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
.myDiv:hover+span{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;    
}
}


a
    {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with a simple CSS solution.
You can use the `~` tilde selector to change properties of another element on hover:

Modified CSS:

```
.myDiv
    {
    width: 200px;    
    }

.myDiv:hover ~ a{
    display:block;
    margin-top:-50px;
    color:red;
}
.myDiv:hover  
    {
    opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }

a
    {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
    display:none;
    }
```

Modified HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv">TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<a href="#">
Click To View More!
</a>
```

Updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/p6go1hdy/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use two sub elements and fade one out and the other in on hover.

```css
.myDiv {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.myDiv > * {  
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
.myDiv .data {
    opacity: 1;
}
.myDiv:hover .data {
    opacity: .1;
}
.subdata {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.myDiv:hover .subdata {
    opacity: 1;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <div class="myDiv">
        <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non tincidunt nulla. Nunc cursus non velit ac commodo. Aliquam rhoncus eros non condimentum volutpat. In eu accumsan eros.</div>
         <div class="subdata">Would you like to know more?</div></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the display of elements within a link on hover. Just need to toggle the opacity of an existing element on roll over.

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/p6go1hdy/2/

HTML:

```
<a class="link" href="#">
<span>TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
    <i>Click here to view more</i>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
    .link{
    width: 200px;    
    }
   .link i {opacity: 0;
    font-style:normal;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;}
   .link:hover span
    {
    opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    }

   a
    {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
    }
.link:hover i {opacity: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to tackle your problem, I personally prefer using jQuery. Of course, you can always implement CSS hover selector if you're more comfortable. 
I first reformatted your HTML structure, removing the CSS hover selector and only work with jQuery. Upon the mouseover event, text will fade out with only the hyperlink visible. As soon as the user moves the mouse away from the text, hovering effect will be disabled.

```
<div class="myDiv">
        <p>TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="more">
        </a>
</div>
```

CSS modifications:

```
.myDiv
{
width: 200px;

}


.more{
color:green;
display:block;
}
.more{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
bottom:60px;
z-index:999;
}
.myDiv > p{
z-index:-1;
transition:all 0.5s easeInOut;
-webkit-transition:all 0.7s easeInOut;
-moz-transition:all 0.7s easeInOut;
-ms-transition:all 0.7s easeInOut; 
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("p").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css('opacity','0.3');
   $(".more").text("click for more").fadeIn('slow');
});
$("p").mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).css('opacity','1');
   $(".more").text("");
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6go1hdy/7/)